# How to call server-script function on HTML Service button click

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a library and have imported into my spreadsheet.

Library file contains these 2 files (sona)

1. customHtml.gs   // UI
2. customScript.gs // Code

Spreadsheet file

1. code.gs

In **customHtml.gs** code (my library)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <input id="txt1" type="text" />
 <input id="txt2" type="text" />
 <input id="Button1" class="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" />

 <script>
 $("#Button1").on('click',function(){

    var param1=$("#txt1").val();
    var param2=$("#txt2").val();
     google.script.run.getCars(param1, param2);
 });
 </script>
```

**customScript.gs**

```
  function sonatask_Assign(){
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('customHtml')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(900)
    .setHeight(500);
    return html;
}

 function getCars(param1, param2){

  // code logic
   Logger.log(param1,param2);
}
```

---

**Spreadsheet (code.gs)**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('► BOT')
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem('Task Assign ', 'fn_task_Assign')
  .addItem('☎ Help ', 'helpMethod')
  .addToUi();
}

// display dialog box with custom HTML (which is stored in library)
 function fn_task_Assign(){
     // get html from library (reason behind using HTML from library, is to acces only specific user. As spreadsheet is availabe to all any one can make a copy of it, but functions will not work unless i acces them to this library )   
     var showHTML = sona.sonatask_Assign();
     Logger.log(abc);
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(showHTML, " "); 
  }
```

On **fn_task_Assign** it display modelbox. i.e. 2 txtbox and a button.
Now on button click I try to call getCars function, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Create getCars inside your code.gs and call sona.getCars();

```
function getCars(param1, param2) {
  sona.getCars(param1, param2);
}
```

Also in oder this all to work, your library needs tobe a Stand alone script. Otherwise it wont work.